# Add duration to time in python

Tags: python

I have two strings:

```
current_time : 4:46:00 PM 
duration : 03:20:00 

current_time is : %I:%M:%S %p
duration is hour:minute:seconds format.
```

I have to add the duration in the time .
In the above case : I need to get the output as  : `08:06:00 PM`
The code that I have tried is :

```
 parsedtime =  time.strptime(current_time,"%I:%M:%S %p")
 parsedduration = time.strptime(duration,"%I:%M:%S")
 parsedtime + datetime.timedelta(parsedduration.tm_hour,parsedduration.tm_min,parsedduration.tm_sec)
 print parsedtime
```

The above is obviously incorrect and not working , please suggest the optimal way.

Comment: Don't mix up `time` and `datetime` like this. Just use one or the other. I'd suggest the latter because it's a lot simpler when you don't have the concepts clear in your head.

Comment: Meanwhile, should 11:00:00 PM + 05:00:00 be 04:00:00 AM always, even if tonight is a DST boundary?

Comment: Yes abarnert ....DST boundry scenario is handeled elsewhere in the code...so it should always be 04:00:00 AM

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is mixing `time` and `datetime` objects and not naming your keyword arguments in `timedelta`.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

current_time = "4:46:00 PM"
duration = "3:20:00"

parsed_time = datetime.strptime(current_time, "%I:%M:%S %p")
parsed_duration = datetime.strptime(duration, "%I:%M:%S")

then = parsed_time + timedelta(hours=parsed_duration.hour,
                               minutes=parsed_duration.minute,
                               seconds=parsed_duration.second)

result = then.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")
# 08:06:00 PM
```

Comment: I later changed my approach to use timedelta but I wasnt using this part of assigning values within timedelta "hours= , minutes= , seconds = " . Thanks a bunch .

Comment: @IshuGupta yes you have to use the kwargs because the default constructor takes (in this order) `days, seconds, microseconds, milliseconds, minutes, hours, weeks`. More info [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta)

Comment: Given his comment that "DST boundry scenario is handeled elsewhere in the code", this will do the wrong thing if today is a DST boundary.

Comment: @abarnert edge cases outnumber regular cases in date&time applications. I'll leave it to OP to implement, but this is the working version of his code.

Comment: @AdamSmith: Using a `datetime` with an unspecified date means you're either going to get today, 1 Jan 1900, or 1 Jan 1970, depending on your platform and your Python version—in other words, unpredictably. And that's exactly why a `datetime` is the wrong thing to use when you don't care about the date: because _it_ still cares about the date, and you haven't told it which date to care about.

Comment: @abarnert fair, but IMO needless. "Time" does not stand alone. If you don't care about the date, either you're Doing It Wrong, or you shouldn't care that `datetime` cares. Meanwhile `datetime` *does* play nice with `timedelta`, and there's no great way to add `time` objects together. Though you may get an arbitrary date, it will at least be a CONSISTENTLY arbitrary date and so happily ignored.

Comment: @AdamSmith: The fact that the stdlib doesn't have functions to add a time and a timedelta (because it would be ambiguous, and rather than pick one of the two options or offering both they chose to offer neither…) doesn't mean you can just use a datetime as if it were a time. It _won't_ be a consistently arbitrary date if you're on a platform that uses today, or run on different platforms, so it may sometimes be off by an hour. But that practical difficulty is only a symptom of the fact that a datetime is not a time in the first place.

Comment: @abarnert I respect your opinion -- what would you suggest instead? I tend to write code that is date-aware even if it's unnecessary so as to move the heavy-lifting of date/time functions to the `datetime` module rather than handling them myself.

Comment: Wait a second… I think in 2.x, `datetime + timedelta` always ignores DST or timezone offset changes, in which case I guess this is all good (although I'd add a comment to that effect, and ideally put it in a wrapper function). If not, you can always construct a UTC datetime and comment _that_, but let me check…

Comment: OK, yeah, checked. Not only does it ignore crossing a boundary for naive datetimes, it even ignores it for _aware_ datetimes. And the "Supported operations" table in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) backs up that this is intentional. The [`pytz`](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) docs explain this as well. So, yeah, this code should work no matter what.

Comment: @abarnert interesting, I had no idea!! Note that this is true also in [Python3x](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects)

Comment: @AdamSmith: Oh, right, I keep forgetting the PEP to fix the timezone stuff didn't make it into 3.3, because Barry convinced the author to go for the bigger change of bundling `pytz` into Python itself in some form or another, which ended up too big of a project. They should have at least just added the `is_dst` param and property and fixed all the problems that allows and put off the rest until later…

Answer (score -3):

```
import datetime
today1= datetime.date.today()
difference= datetime.timedelta(1)
yesterday= today1 - difference
print (yesterday)
```

It will give you a point, for example this one finds today-1day. It means yesterday.

```
time1= time.localtime()
hour1=time1.tm_hour
min1=tim1.tm_min
#do your codes#
```

So you can define hour and min as a variable and do math.